# PEAR packages installed in wrong directory and fails suggestions in PHP Storm

Tags: window, phpunit, pear

I've struggled too long installing PHPUnit from PEAR. As you can see below the installed files are not in the php_dir directory I have set, which means that PhpStorm cannot find the files and help me with suggestions.

Also, is it expected that the installed file is without extension??

```
D:\Code\www\energimolnet\api-backend\protected>pear config-get php_dir
D:\xampp\php\pear\

D:\Code\www\energimolnet\api-backend\protected>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
downloading PHPUnit-4.0.6.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-4.0.6.tgz (510,745 bytes)
......done: 510,745 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-4.0.6

D:\Code\www\energimolnet\api-backend\protected>pear list-files phpunit/PHPUnit
INSTALLED FILES FOR PHPUNIT/PHPUNIT
===================================
TYPE   INSTALL PATH
doc    C:\php\pear\docs\PHPUnit\LICENSE
doc    C:\php\pear\docs\PHPUnit\README.md
script D:\xampp\php\phpunit
script D:\xampp\php\phpunit.bat

D:\Code\www\energimolnet\api-backend\protected>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on Windows, poor soul, use the D:\xampp\php\phpunit.bat script.

If you still have no joy, try doing:

```
$ pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: yeah... Windows causes many issues for me. I tried to install PHPUnit 3.7 the exact same way and that worked as expected. When I I run the *.bat script nothing happens as far as I can see. What should happen?

Comment: Did you try forcing the issue, by doing a $pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit ? That might do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I did try that too. Didn't change anything... I'll go for the manual way for now, and then in a soon future I'll move to *nix system.